# How to get fb:app_id for facebook meta

Tags: facebook

We have out business profile page as http://facebook.com/geoflakes , and i can get its id from 
http://graph.facebook.com/geoflakes

My Business Like Page as http://facebook.com/geoflake and i can get its id from 
http://graph.facebook.com/geoflake

My Facebook developer app as "Geoflake" and its id is "132427906799290"

Which id, i have to use for fb:app_id in the meta tags. ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The latter one, because `http://graph.facebook.com/geoflake` returns the **page id** of your business profile page.