# When do I need a fb:app_id or fb:admins?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The doc for the facebook like button says , "When your Web page represents a real-world entity, things like movies, sports teams, celebrities, and restaurants, use the Open Graph protocol to specify information about the entity."

I'm adding like buttons to a blog posts/videos/articles which aren't really entities. Right? So I don't need fb:app_id or fb:admins? But then in step 2 of creating a like button is says, "Get Open Graph Tags" and when I use Linter to validate my like buttons without fb:admins and fb:app_id I get a "fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing."

If it turns out that I need fb:admins and fb:app_id tags do I need to have a Facebook like page to find them?

Also is it fb:admins AND fb:app_id or fb:admins OR fb:app_id, I can't tell if I need both or not.

And in the graph.facebook/somepage it gives an id, but what id is that? For example:
[How to get fb:app_id for facebook meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307324/how-to-get-fbapp-id-for-facebook-meta)

Answer (score 91):

Including the `fb:app_id` tag in your HTML HEAD will allow the Facebook scraper to associate the Open Graph entity for that URL with an application. This will allow any admins of that app to view Insights about that URL and any social plugins connected with it.

The `fb:admins` tag is similar, but allows you to just specify each user ID that you would like to give the permission to do the above.

You can include either of these tags or both, depending on how many people you want to admin the Insights, etc. A single as `fb:admins` is pretty much a minimum requirement. The rest of the Open Graph tags will still be picked up when people share and like your URL, however it may cause problems in the future, so please include one of the above.

fb:admins is specified like this:
`<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>`
OR
`<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID,USER_ID2,USER_ID3"/>`

and fb:app_id like this:
`<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APPID"/>`

Comment: Facebook required me to get a `fb:app_id`, but I didn't want to give my phone number in order to register as a Developer, so I just removed the tag. `fb:adimns` alone worked just fine.

Comment: FB was not scraping our default image and meta content because we listed two admins, one in each tag, before the rest of the meta data. So it was apparently crashing. We removed both fb:admins meta tags, in favor of the fb:app_id tag and everything is now working.

Comment: This answer is of its time, and I can't guarantee that things have stayed the same with regard to using both tags, or whether they're still used etc.

Comment: Facebook has updated their docs, you now need multiple `fb:admins` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#moderation-setup-instructions

Answer (score 16):

To use the Like Button and have the Open Graph inspect your website, you need an application.

So you need to associate the Like Button with a `fb:app_id`

If you want other users to see the administration page for your website on Facebook you add `fb:admins`. So if you are the developer of the application and the website owner there is no need to add `fb:admins`

Comment: What if I don't have an App?

Comment: Facebook calls any website that uses open graph tags an "app"; the website doesn't even need to be interactive, it can be 100% static and is still an "app" to Facebook for the purposes of getting this ID and accessing the analytics through it. It's a bit confusing terminology.

Answer (score 6):

I think the documentation is reasonably helpful!

If you read it again, it says that adding open graph elements on your website will make your website act as a facebook page and you'll get the ability to publish updates to them etc.

So I think it's up to you - you can either just have a page with no OG elements, which is less work but also less 'rewarding' for you.

If you do use og, then set type to: `blog`

Finally: `fb:admins` **or** `fb:app_id` - A comma-separated list of either the Facebook IDs of page administrators or a Facebook Platform application ID. **At a minimum, include only your own Facebook ID.**

So just put your own fbid in there. As a tip, you can easily get this by looking at the url of your profile photo on facebook.

Comment: "A comma-separated list of either the Facebook IDs of page administrators or a Facebook Platform application ID. At a minimum, include only your own Facebook ID." — I've tested this. It doesn't work that way. You have to include the tag one time per ID.