# The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, typo3, meta-tags

in my TYPO3 Installation i have some meta tags with og: in it.

now Facebooks linter said:

> The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'og:image:url, fb:admins'

these are my meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://abele-optik.de/typo3temp/pics/586bc01dd7.jpg" />    
<meta property="og:image" content="http://abele-optik.de/typo3temp/pics/47eeec7031.jpg" />    
<meta property="og:image" content="http://abele-optik.de/typo3temp/pics/4b5d6914a2.jpg" />    
<meta property="og:image" content="http://abele-optik.de/typo3temp/pics/88765247db.jpg" />    
<meta property="og:image" content="http://abele-optik.de/typo3temp/pics/b5f783dea7.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://abele-optik.de/typo3temp/pics/0fc37f4a10.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://abele-optik.de/typo3temp/pics/8c13fb9af5.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://abele-optik.de/typo3temp/pics/fe79697ba3.jpg" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100001266982853" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://abele-optik.de/angebote/angebot-kinderbrillen.html" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Abele-Optik GmbH:Angebot Kinderbrillen" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="OiO-Titanflex-Kinderbrillen" />
```

this is the output of the linter tool:

Graph API:  https://graph.facebook.com/579080578799158

Is there something wrong with the order of the og-tags? I cant find something about it on FB -

thx for an answer and yes: i searched before i write here..

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the complete output of https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fabele-optik.de%2Fangebote%2Fangebot-kinderbrillen.html

It says:

> Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'http://abele-optik.de/uploads/tx_flexslider/ABELE_slider_AngebShopAug_01.jpg' will be used instead.

I think this will solve the first problem. The second one may be caused because you have specified `fb:admins` but not an `fb:app_id` ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836135/when-do-i-need-a-fbapp-id-or-fbadmins)).

Comment: But if there is no app, what does the admin do?

Comment: Again: why is there an admin specified in the html code of the website when it is not loaded into facebook directly (but only by share-links)? What does this user do? I think you can just leave it out.

Comment: where can i find the app_id of this site? there is a like link on website.

Comment: As you don't have an app, but a simple facebook page, there is no app id. Hence, there is nothing an admin could do. What is your admin user supposed to do?

Comment: Admins And App ID Missing: fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing. These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.

Comment: And the Images are min 300px height and width: http://abele-optik.de/typo3temp/pics/fbd42f2338.jpg

Comment: Ok, then ignore the facebook hint. It just makes no sense if you do not have an app which is used in a tab page. Are the preview images correct when you try to share the given URL? If yes, you can also ignore the other hint as well.

Comment: yes, the links are ok. it is horrible - is facebook doing what it want? what can i do? im tired..

Comment: And no, the preview thumbnails in die little FB blowout is not ok. It takes a picture which is nowwhere definied - i think its a cache of FB.. - thats horrible...

Comment: now i have tested the share button from: http://zenverse.net/legacy-facebook-share-button-code/ - with this code i got all preview thumbnails in the blowout box.. - thats ill - the new like button does not work?

Comment: hey Michael, can you tell me the why this code does not work? When i do the code http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u= in a link as href, then it works on the site! With all og:images. When i do this code in it, only the first og:image is for the like given. - i dont understand this.. - this ist the code i get from FB like-button generator: