# Open Graph (OG tags) are not working when i post in social media

Tags: seo, social-media

In My website i tried Og tags in below way but it is not work 
1. image height and weight 
2. Not accepting og:url
3. Not accepting og:Video url and og:video:secure_url
4. og:title not visible after publish on social media

```
<meta name="title" content="Officegx" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Officegx, Office"  />
        <meta name="description" content="Officegx, OfficeGx"  />
        <meta name="og:title" content="OfficeGx Og Tag" />
        <meta name="og:type" content="OfficeGx Og Tag" />
        <meta name="og:url" content="https://www.officegx.com/a/339552/project-management-software-system" />
        <meta name="og:image" content="https://s7.postimg.org/qh021h14r/Minify_CSS_files.png" />
        <meta name="og:image:url" content="https://s7.postimg.org/qh021h14r/Minify_CSS_files.png" />
        <meta name="og:image:secure_url" content="https://s7.postimg.org/qh021h14r/Minify_CSS_files.png" />
        <meta name="og:image:type" content="OfficeGx image" />
        <meta name="og:image:width" content="400" />
        <meta name="og:image:height" content="100" />
        <meta name="og:image:alt" content="officeGx alt Tag" />
        <meta name="og:video:width" content="400" />
    <meta name="og:video:height" content="100" />
```

could you please help me

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the following properties:

- fb:admins
- fb:app_id
- prefix for example for video, og.

```html
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# video: http://ogp.me/ns/video#">
```

**[Object Properties OG](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-properties)** + **[Reference documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/)** + **[video.other](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/video.other/)**

Comment: fb:admins
fb:app_id these these fields are mandatory ? and i gave vodeo URL in this way <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/bond/trailer.swf" />

Comment: These is for only facebook but i need all soical media platforms for OG tags.
could please suggest what to need to change in my code

Comment: @Devender These identifiers are required. Each Facebook Page has a unique ID associated with it. https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=1041828329232240 ++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836135/when-do-i-need-a-fbapp-id-or-fbadmins

Comment: @Devender If you want to create a rich SERP refer to structured data https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data

Comment: yes but OG tags are not only for facebook. what about Twitter, googleplus and other social media platforms. i tried in this fb:admins, fb:app_id also but i need those og tags for all social media platforms. can you please suggest

Comment: @Devender https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started